# How can I optimize this floodFill algorithm? Advice needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I have a fiddle with the following code. [ColorWalk clone](https://jsfiddle.net/416vr2uj/1/)

Here is the js code:

```
function floodFill(x, y, selectedColor, grayColor) {
  if (x < 0 || x >= 600) return;
  if (y < 0 || y >= 400) return;
  let square = $('.blockattribute').filter(function(ind, el) {
    return $(el).css('left') == x + 'px' && $(el).css('top') == y + 'px'
  });
  let squareColor = square.css('background-color');
  if (squareColor === grayColor || squareColor === selectedColor) {
    square.removeClass().addClass('blockattribute gray');
    floodFill(x + 20, y, selectedColor, grayColor);
    floodFill(x, y + 20, selectedColor, grayColor);
    floodFill(x - 20, y, selectedColor, grayColor);
    floodFill(x, y - 20, selectedColor, grayColor);
  }
  else {
    return;
  }
}
```

I've been working on learning javascript/jquery and algorithms and I've pretty much have this clone working except for the fact that when I get deeper and deeper into the grid, the slower and slower the code is. I've been reading about memoization and trying to use it on the grid but I'm getting stuck as to how to approach. All I'm really looking for is a little push regarding how to do this. Maybe memoization isn't the way to go and maybe I can optimize my code some other way. My current thinking is that I need to grab the last gray square and then proceed from there. Am I on the right track?

----Edit------

I realized that I can combine the `if/else` operator to check for matching gray color or selected color

Comment: Should next call to function wait for return value from last call to function?

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply @guest271314. What do you mean by wait for the return of the last function? Isn't already being processed?

Comment: Hey @guest271314, I could really use some help and I'm trying to figure out exactly what you mean by having the next function wait for the return value of the previous function. Are you talking about something like in this stackoverflow question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724384/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-return-value

Comment: Yes. What is purpose of calling function twice or four times? Or is function only called once?

Comment: I made some edits to the code that I have right now. I'm calling it four times because I'm passing in different values each time. I'm checking square colors in the above, below, left, and right spaces. That's why I'm calling it four times. For reference I'm using this link with the explanation. http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2011/08/11/recursion-explained-with-the-flood-fill-algorithm-and-zombies-and-cats/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading from and writing to the DOM are very expensive in Javascript. You also should never use the DOM as the source of your data.

To speed up your algorithm, store the pixel data offline as regular Javascript data, manipulate the data only, then update the visual code only once. This way you minimize the number of DOM operations.

Additionally, Javascript is not "tail call optimized," meaning you can't recurse forever, and every level of recursion will slow down the program to some degree. If you can use a non-recursive flood fill algorithm in this case, it will likely be faster.

Comment: _"Javascript is not "tail call optimized" meaning you can't recurse forever"_ Is tail call optimization equivalent to recursion?

Comment: Thanks @Andy Ray, so are you getting at that instead of DOM elements, I would have to construct an array like grid with javascript and once I manipulate that, I can update the DOM. Is that correct?

Comment: Dan: Yes. Separate your view from your data. guest2713: what?